# Javascript:-Embedded "For Loop" is not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to implement a for loop embedded in HTML to print the values in an array. This is what I did:

```
var arr = [];
    for (var id in order.cart.items) {
        arr.push(order.cart.items[id]);
    }
    console.log()
let mailOptions = {

from: "John Doe"+"<johndoe@gmail.com>", // TODO: email sender
to:email , // TODO: email receiver
subject: 'Order Confirmation',
html: "<script>"+"<br>"+ "var i;"+ "<br>" + 
"for("+"i="+0+";"+"i<"+arr.length+";"+"i++" +")"+"{"+arr[i].item.title+"}"+"<br>"+"</script>"}
```

The problem is with the html part in mailOptions. The for loop does not seem to be working. The array is getting values, but the error shown is: i is not defined. How can I do this? What is wrong in the above syntax? The array is working properly. If I put arr[0] or arr[1] in place of arr[i], everything works properly

Comment: Why do you have br tags inside of the script tag? A script tag is supposed to contain script only.

Comment: OK,I removed the br tags,But still it is not working.

Comment: `arr[i].item.title` in the loop doesn't do anything, it just retrieves the value and doesn't use it anywhere. I suppose you also need to escape the ending script tag in the string, ex. `<\/script>` to not break the outer script.

Comment: if I do arr[0].item.title then it is showing the value in Html .But here the problem is with 'i' it can't access the 'i' .It is always showing 'i' is not defined.

Comment: If you're going to run this in an email, then `arr` would be undefined ... And definitely retrieving a value from an array in JS doesn't show on a page, this is not PHP.

Comment: But i used the arr in email only .It is not undefined .It is giving me the output correctly in an email. Main problem is with syntax and declaration of variable i as for loop is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only instance of `i` I see in this code is `+arr[i].item.title+`.

But you don't have the variable `i` declared inside this script that's making this mailOptions, only inside the script tag you're trying to write inside the mailOptions html.

Maybe I'm missing something or we're missing part of the code ( is this code part of some other for-loop that's not shown? Otherwise it seems logical to me that the `i is not defined` error is about this script, not the embedded one.

**EDIT:**

Alot of things do not make sense here, since `arr` and `i` are not part of the same script, but i think you might be looking for this instead of embedding a script tag:

```js
var order = {
  cart: {
    items: {
      id_123: { item: { title: "val123" }},
      id_456: { item: { title: "val456" }},
      id_789: { item: { title: "val789" }}
    }
  }
};
var arr = [];
for (var id in order.cart.items) {
    arr.push(order.cart.items[id]);
}
var email = 'a@a.vcom';
var html = '';
var i;
for ( i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
  html += arr[i].item.title + '<br>';
}

let mailOptions = {
  from: "John Doe"+"<johndoe@gmail.com>", // TODO: email sender
  to: email , // TODO: email receiver
  subject: 'Order Confirmation',
  html: html
};
console.log( mailOptions );
```

Is this what you're after? Including all the order items inside the email as HTML? instead of trying to embed a script tag?

Comment: But I have defined var i in Html before for loop.

Comment: That's my entire point. I think the error is not about the script inside the HTML, since it has `var i;`. It's about how `+ arr[i].item.title +` refers to an `i` inside this `var arr = []; for ( var id in ... )...` part of the script, where it does not exist.  If you use `i`, it should be text, so maybe you want to write `"{arr[i].item.title}"`, so that the i is actually about the script in the HTML. But then `arr` will be undefined. So I do not understand what you're trying to do with only the code shown. It'll obv throw an error since `var i` is text while you are creating mailOptions.

Comment: Yes i have some values in  an array and now i have to send the values in an email. So i want to access that values .So for this I have to use for or while loop to access all the elements of an array. The problem is in syntax and for loop only .Because i printed the arr[0].item.title It is perfectly showing the value in my email.So task is to access all the elements of an array

Comment: What you say makes no sense, since `arr` and `i` are not aprt fo the same script. But wait, I'll write an answer, since i think I see what's going on here.

Comment: See the above script has nothing to do with the mail Options .It is just for feeding the data in an array. The problem is with the "for loop" in the HTML .Because i can access the array element manually. Like arr[0].item.title or arr[1].item.title and so on.. It is showing me the output. But i coudn't do it manually bcoz i have to use  for or while loop in Html.Now it should make sense bcoz We have the array of items .Now we have to print it in Html page?Then How will you do it?

Comment: Yupp it works ..Thanks a lot!! and sorry for the inconvenience caused as i did not define the all things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i can imagine it has trouble parsing your embedded script. What is it you are trying to achieve? If you want to create a list of items, why don't you create a function instead, that returns a list of items in plain html?

Comment: I just want to know how should i include the for or while loop.Because However if i wrote any function then also I have to use for loop to print the items of that array in HTML